# mvc razor Html.Raw("</div><div class=\"newDiv\">") is not outputting it as raw

Tags: razor

```
<text>@this.Html.Raw("</div><div class=\"newDiv\">").ToString()</text>
```

I'm trying to output `</div><div class="newDiv">` as-is in the view, but, it's encoding it for me so that I can see the <'s and the >'s.  Any other way of doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the `ToString()` causing the problem. `Html.Raw` returns a special `HtmlString` telling Razor it doesn't need to be encoded, but then you're turning it straight back in to a regular string which does get encoded. Just use:

```
@Html.Raw("</div><div class=\"newDiv\">")
```